# Predicting python script in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, rstudio, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am an R user currently learning python.
In RStudio, when I type a piece of code, it automatically gives me predictions of the functions I am looking for - like an autocomplete.
I would like to have something similar in Jupyter Lab. Is it possible?

Comment: JupyterLab usually uses `jedi` for autocomplete. But you have to trigger it with <tab>.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-completion is supported in Jupyter already. You could try type `enu` and then hit tab. This `enumerate` will prompt out automatically.